# Regex To match all of scss including nested classes etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, sass

I need a RegEx that will match a while entire scss class and properties including nested elements for example

```
.class {
  @include mixin() {
    do stuff...
  }

  background: pink;

  > h1 {
    color: blue;
  }

  .class-2 {
    font-size: 1000px;
  }
}
```

not match white space after that class in the file and then match any other scss class

```
.class {
  stuff...
}
```

not match whitespace....

```
.class5 {stuff...}
```

not match if no whitespace either

```
h1.class7 {stuff}
```

etc. I think this is understandable if not I can further clarify
I currently have an expression that almost works but it doesn't account for nested classes or anything like that. `\.?.+\{[\S\s]+?\}`

Comment: What is the expression you have that almost works?

Comment: So, JS regex doesn't support recursion. So, it can't match any nesting.

Comment: You could try something like  [`[^\s}{]+\s*{(?:[^}{]+|{[^}{]*})*}`](https://regex101.com/r/liXDzV/2) (this is for max one level of nesting and not very efficient).

Comment: just added my current regex

Comment: @bobblebubble I get a Catastrophic Backtracking with that

Comment: You can create a Regex that matches the pattern or the nested pattern then write a function that applies that regex recursively.

Comment: @sln which Regex can do recursion

Comment: i found xregexp that can match recursivley, how would I do that?

Comment: Mostly PCRE/Perl https://regex101.com/r/I1C2Yy/1 but not JS, Java, Python (although import regex can).
https://regex101.com/r/I1C2Yy/2